# how to get innerTextwithin the node in HTML AGILity pack..?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
<a> contents <strong>strong content</strong> </a>
```

I want a only the "contents" i.e present between `<a>` and `<strong>`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to remove the string within `<strong>` from string within `<a>` -

```
var testString = "<a> contents <strong>strong content</strong> </a>";
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(testString);
var strWithinAnchor = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/a").InnerText;
var strWithinStrong = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/a/strong").InnerText;
var resultString = strWithinAnchor.Replace(strWithinStrong, string.Empty);
```